# WAS 8.5.9 Datasource failed......DSRA0010E: SQL State = 42601, Error Code = -104 getting error code in Application

Tags: websphere-8

I am using WAS 8.5.9 version, looks like some datasource connection problem but when I click on test connection button in WAS console it is showing connection is fine.But When I am running my application it is throwing error and in Error logs it is showing below error

```
[financing_tools_docgen] [DBConnection] [04/27 14:18:45.759] [ERROR] [Severity 2] [[abcdefd@gmail.com][145681]] getConnection() : Got SQLException :com.ibm.websphere.ce.cm.StaleConnectionException: DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-104, SQLSTATE=42601, SQLERRMC=SNAPSHOT;MODE, DRIVER=3.57.82 DSRA0010E: SQL State = 42601, Error Code = -104
```

In Application logs getting below error

```
[financing_tools_docgen] [DBConnection] [04/27 14:18:43.723] [DEBUG] [Severity 4] [[abcded@gmail.com][145681]] Trying to get connection object with ICFS DS=ICFS_IR1T , JNDI value=jdbc/financing_tools_docgen_txtmgr 
[financing_tools_docgen] [DBConnection] [04/27 14:18:45.759] [ERROR] [Severity 2] [[abcded@gmail.com][145681]] getConnection() : Got SQLException :com.ibm.websphere.ce.cm.StaleConnectionException: DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-104, SQLSTATE=42601, SQLERRMC=SNAPSHOT;MODE, DRIVER=3.57.82 DSRA0010E: SQL State = 42601, Error Code = -104
```

Comment: this question looks related to the problem you are seeing: https://developer.ibm.com/answers/questions/182641/websphere-adapter-for-jdbc-receives-db2-sql-error.html

Answer (score 0):

Here is the DB2 documentation for SQLState 42601 with Error Code -104,

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.messages.sql.doc/doc/msql00104n.html

It sounds like a syntax error rather than a stale connection.  I think the application server has misclassified it here.  That would be consistent with test connection operation still working, because connection can be obtained successfully, but the error is occurring when executing a SQL command with a syntax error. You should look into the SQL that is being used and see if you can correct.